# How to create a unique for a combination of 2 columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, unique

I have a persons table with firstname, lastname, password, email, phone, etc

I want to create a unique constraint where many people can have the same firstname or more than one person can have the same email address (in case household uses only one) but no two people can have the same firstname and email address at the same time

Is this possible?

Comment: Just an aside... if the family does use a single email address, and the son is named after the father?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute this DDL statement.

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT tb_UQ UNIQUE(firstname, email)
```